# How to find specific tuple inside array of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I got an array of tuples, each tuple contains (string, string), and I want to find specific tuple inside the array.

example:

```
[("command","ABCDEFG"),("arguments","XYZW"),("time","ERRTY")]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "find"? Check if a tuple exists in your array? Find its location? Find based of its first or second element? Or anything else?

Comment: Are you trying to find based on the first string, the second string, or both? Does it vary what you are searching by (sometimes first string sometimes both)? Are you looking for the closest match if there is no match exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `in` keyword:

```
('foo', 'bar') in [('foo', 'bar'),('spam', 'eggs')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert these tuples to `dict` and search by first element:

```
list_of_tuples = [("command","ABCDEFG"),("arguments","XYZW"),("time","ERRTY")]

d = dict(list_of_tuples)

print(d['arguments'])
```

Prints:

```
XYZW
```

Edit: to check if some key exists in dictionary, use `in` operator, eg.:

```
if 'arguments' in d:
    print(d['arguments'])
else:
    print('Not found!')
```

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful.

Comment: Good approach but because of the possible KeyError, it may be better to use `d.get('arguments')`. Like `if d.get('arguments'): print('Yes!') else: print('No!')`. Or simply `'arguments' in d` will return a `True/False` automatically